# Generate the hardware interupt which will enable the CapsLock

Tags: macos, qt, macos-carbon

I want to Send my machine an hardware event so that my caps-lock key becomes enable. When I send enable interrupt, light on Caps-lock key should be on and when I send enable interrupt, light on Caps-lock key should be off.

I am using Qt, Mac, C++, Carbon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for an interrupt. [The Caps Lock, Num Lock, and Scroll Lock lights are programmatically controllable.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/HID_LED_test_tool/)

Note that this won't actually turn the Caps Lock on (causing the user to enter all-capital text), but you shouldn't do that. If you need text input to be in a specific format, then you should make any needed repairs to it—which may include capitalizing it—yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code. I've been looking for a way to turn on/off caps lock light on OS-X for several days already. Of course it would be  even better if I could not just turn on/off the light, but really turn on/off caps-lock (just turning on the light won't make letters upper-case). Do you also know a code sample how this can be done?

Comment: Mecki: See what I said in my answer.

Comment: @PeterHosey It seems the link you shared doesn't show any code. :-/

Comment: @silvioprog Apple moved it and (as usual) didn't bother to set up a redirect to the new location. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

Can you even generate a HW interrupt from a non-privileged userspace application on OS X. It sound to me as if this is something that you should request the OS to do (i.e. turn on or off Caps Lock)